# Odoo 13.0 Invoice PDF rendering, elements overlapping each other

Tags: odoo, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-13

I have an Issue with the Odoo PDF rendering of the Invoice App. Problem is that my header and the main content are overlapping each other when rendered as PDF. Also the footer gets cut off.

I've managed via the developer mode to create a copy of the external_layout_standard, modify it and set it as document layout in the general settings. It looks good in the web view but as soon as I try to render the PDF-file things get weird.

I think Odoo uses wkhtmltopdf if that information is any helpful.

The Template I use

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="web.my_custom_layout">
  <div t-attf-class="header">
    <div class="row text-right">
      <div class="col-12">
        <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="image_data_uri(company.logo)" style="max-width: 300px; margin-right: 50px" alt="Logo"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8" style="margin-top: 50px">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li t-if="company.name" class="list-inline-item"><span t-field="company.name"/>,</li>
          <li t-if="company.street" class="list-inline-item"><span t-field="company.street"/>,</li>
          <li t-if="company.zip and company.city" class="list-inline-item"><span t-field="company.zip"/> <span t-field="company.city"/></li>
        </ul>
        <t t-if="address">
          <div class="address row">
            <div name="address" class="col-12">
              <t t-raw="address"/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </t>
      </div>
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12" name="company_address">
            <div t-field="company.partner_id"
                 t-options="{'widget': 'contact', 'fields': ['address', 'name'], 'no_marker': true}"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12" name="company_phone">
            Telefon
            <div t-field="company.partner_id"
                 t-options="{'widget': 'contact', 'fields': ['phone'], 'no_marker': true}"/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <p>
              buchhaltung<br/>
              @my-company.com
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div t-if="company.vat">Steuer-Nr.: <strong t-field="company.vat"/><br/></div>
            <div>UStID-Nr.: <strong>XXXXXXXXXXX</strong><br/></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div t-attf-class="article"
       t-att-data-oe-model="o and o._name" t-att-data-oe-id="o and o.id"
       t-att-data-oe-lang="o and o.env.context.get('lang')">
    <t t-raw="0"/>
  </div>

  <div t-attf-class="footer">
    <div style="border-top: 1px solid black; padding-top: 20px">
      <div name="financial_infos">
        <span t-field="company.report_footer"/>
      </div>
      <div t-if="company.name" class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Zahlungsempfänger</div>
        <div class="col-8"><span t-field="company.name"/></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Bankverbindung</div>
        <div class="col-8">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-8">BIC XXXXXXXXXXX, IBAN XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Bankverbindung</div>
        <div class="col-8">XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"></div>
        <div class="col-8">BIC XXXXXXXX, IBAN XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4"><strong>Geschäftsführung</strong></div>
        <div t-if="company.company_registry" class="col-8"><strong>Registergericht/Nr.</strong></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">Here goes CEO</div>
        <div t-if="company.company_registry" class="col-8"><span t-field="company.company_registry"/></div>
      </div>

      <div t-if="report_type == 'pdf'" class="text-muted">
        Page: <span class="page"/> / <span class="topage"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</t>
```

In web view everything is fine: [Invoice how it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzz8T.png)

In the PDF-file all information are there but gets overlapped by the header
[PDF-file](https://file.io/wlI47O4E)
[Screenshot of PDF-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfkOq.png)

There were some steps I already tried:

- In the System Parameters I set the web.base.url. That fixed some initial render problems.
- I also tried setting web.base.url.freeze to True. But that didn't change a thing.
- Removing the footer changed nothing.
- Removing parts of the template changed nothing
- Overwriting the initial layout external_layout_standard changed nothing

I am thankful for any help

Comment: Did you try to play around with the paperformat header/footer setting?

Comment: Yeah that was the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CZoellner I could fix it with editing the format settings under General Settings > Business Documents > Format.

Just added some Top and Bottom margin and it was fixed